# How to set the frame of a ViewController without storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, view, viewcontroller

I want to create a view (e.g. 100x100) with ViewController without using the storyboard. I am wondering what the best way to declare the frame of the ViewController is.

I tried:

```
class MyLittleViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
        view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    }
}
```

And I tried to see this view on my MainViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let myLittleView = MyLittleViewController()
    myLittleView.willMove(toParent: self)
    myLittleView.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    myLittleView.view.backgroundColor = .red
    view.addSubview(myLittleView.view)
    // enable auto-sizing (for example, if the device is rotated)
    myLittleView.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    self.addChild(myLittleView)
    myLittleView.didMove(toParent: self)

    myLittleView.view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    myLittleView.view.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

It doesn't work like I expected because the little view doesn't appear on the main view. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't mix frame layout with auto-layout set a width & height constraints also

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    myLittleView.view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
    myLittleView.view.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
    myLittleView.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:100),
    myLittleView.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:100)
])
```

**OR**

```
myLittleView.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100) 
myLittleView.view.center = view.center
```

**OR**

```
override func loadView() {
    view = UIView()
    view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
}
```

---

**Edit:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
           self.view.backgroundColor = .green
        let myLittleView = MyLittleViewController()
        myLittleView.willMove(toParent: self)
        myLittleView.view.backgroundColor = .red
        view.addSubview(myLittleView.view)
        // enable auto-sizing (for example, if the device is rotated)
        myLittleView.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        self.addChild(myLittleView)
        myLittleView.didMove(toParent: self)
        myLittleView.view.center = view.center
    }
}

class MyLittleViewController: UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
        view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to set the frame inside the class MyLittleViewController?

Comment: Thanks now it works, previously it did not worked due to         myLittleView.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false, but I don't know why

Comment: `myLittleView.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` is used when you set constraints programmatically

Comment: you are right, but when I set constraints programmatically I still can't use  ```myLittleView.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false ```, but the constraints work.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to set frame of the view controller is override method loadView() and set the view frame like this

```
func loadView() {
   view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work :(, when it runs it gives me an error:  Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16b697ee0).

Comment: @EdoardodeCal you need to create a new view

Comment: @Sh_Khan I tried to use:     override func loadView() {
        view = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    }

Comment: @Sh_Khan no it doesn't :(, it doesn't show the view.

Comment: Yes, I tried to use your code, but the view doesn't appear.

Comment: sr, i miss. you have to init uiview first